# generics in kotlin - type that implement an interface restriction

Tags: generics, kotlin

```
fun membershipSelected(membershipSelected: List<MemberShipType>) = apply { this.membershipSelected= membershipSelected}


object GOLD: MemberShipType("Gold"), IRateOption{}

object BRONZE: MemberShipType("Bronze"){}
```

In Kotlin, how can I restrict `membershipSelected` to be only `MembershipTypes` which implement `IRateOption` interface?

For example, BRONZE, does not implement `IRateOption`, but `GOLD` does so only `GOLD` can be selected as `membershipType`

Comment: I think you need to create a class that will extend your class and implement the interface, then and use it as parameter type instead. As far as I'm aware it's not possible (at compile time) to double check the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a generic with a `where` clause, as [documented in the Kotlin manual](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints). For your use case, it would look like this:

```
fun <T> membershipSelected(membershipSelected: List<T>): ReturnType
    where T : MembershipType,
          T : IRateOption {
    // function body
}
```

Or, with shorthand syntax:

```
fun <T> membershipSelected(membershipSelected: List<T>) where T : MembershipType, T : IRateOption = // function body
```

**Edit**: This solution will only work if all the items in the parameter are of the same type. This means you won't be able to use two separate classes/objects that are subtypes of `MembershipType` and `IRateOption`. If you need this behavior, I'd recommend creating an open or abstract class, like so:

```
abstract class RateMembershipType(...) : MembershipType(...), IRateOption

object GOLD: RateMembershipType(...)
object BRONZE: MembershipType(...)

fun membershipSelected(membershipSelected: List<RateMembershipType>) = ...
```

Comment: thanks, it is partly working. can you update answer so that membershipSelected can be more than one Type. I think it is restricting to one ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. If that's the behavior you need, I would recommend creating an open or abstract class along the lines of `open class RateMembershipType(...) : MembershipType(...), IRateOption`.

Comment: @M06H I've added an edit to my answer. For future reference, please try to list all the requirements in the original question so that we can provide the most accurate answer.